# Azure Based OData Query Failure with Socket Errors

Tags: azure-devops, odata

I have three apps querying the same data service on Azure. One has no issues, but two of them are receiving "errors. They are using a Linq query, i.e. "System.Linq.IQueryable queryResult = entities.Accts.Where(a => a.AN == "XXX");"

The errors are: 
    1. WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
    2. IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    3. SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Interesting, having captured the actual sent "request" communication messages from the failing apps and using them in a browser, I get good responses, not errors.

I actually took copies of the OData connection files from the working app and used them to replace their equivalents in a copy of a failing app with no success; same errors.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Working with MS, it appears that a new protocol is in effect requiring the following statement be added to our code:

```
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Any more explanation on this? Why is it needed? How does this fix the problem?

Comment: Actually, with MS Support's help, in the end what I discovered was the Azure databases were renamed because I had created new SQL Servers in prep for scaling and moved the databases to them. During the move the database names were appended with a data/time stamp, requiring me to change the connection strings.